# Pass knockout foreach object to Html.HiddenFor

Tags: html, knockout.js

I need to pass a value of an object in `foreach` loop of knockout into an `@Html.HiddenFor`. Is it possible to do so? Here is my code:

```
<!-- ko foreach: Products-->
<div class="well">
    <h3>
        <strong data-bind="text: Name"></strong>
        <span class="pull-right label label-primary" data-bind="text: formatCurrency(Price)"></span>
    </h3>

   @using (Html.BeginForm("AddToCart", "Cart"))
   {
        <div class="pull-right">
            @Html.HiddenFor(x=> x.ProductId)
            @Html.Hidden("returnUrl", Request.Url.PathAndQuery)
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Add to cart"/>
        </div>
    }

    <span class="lead" data-bind="text: Description"></span>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Maybe there is some analogue for it since I know that `@Html.HiddenFor` is executed on the server, while Knockout is client-side? I am new to MVC development, and can't tell if it is a good idea to use Knockout in this particular view, maybe I should just allow items to be rendered on the server side?

Comment: the HiddenFor is just a bit of boilerplate C# which generates standard HTML hidden field markup to be rendered on the client and populates it with the value from the C# model. It probably has an ID of "ProductId". It's that element which your JS code can target. Inspect the source code of the finished page in your browser and you'll see it.

Comment: Thank you so much!